# linked-list in C showing the last 2 elements only

Tags: c, linked-list

I tried to list the linked-list, but i got a weird result. It looks like my list is NULL even if I add elements to it. The function insertFin adds element to the end of the list. affichListe lists the content of the list.
What I did is created a list called Node then gave it an alias liste using `typdef Node list;`. the weird things that my list always list the last two elements.

````
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct Node
{
    int x;
    Node *next;
};

typedef Node list;


void insertFin(list** first, int x)
{
    list* nouvElem = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
    nouvElem->x = x;
    nouvElem->next = NULL;
    
    if(*first == NULL)
    {
        *first = nouvElem;
    }
    
    else
    {
        while((*first)->next != NULL)
        {
            *first = (*first)->next;
        }
        (*first)->next = nouvElem;
    }
}


void affichListe(list* first)
{
    while(first != NULL)
    {
        printf("x = %i\n",first->x);
        first = first->next;
    }
    
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    list* l = NULL;
    insertFin(&l,1);
    insertFin(&l,2);
    insertFin(&l,6);
    insertFin(&l,7);
    insertFin(&l,8);
    affichListe(l);

}```
````

Comment: `first = &(*first)->next;`

Comment: BTW: you don't need the if/else.

Answer (score 0):

In this loop:

```
    while((*first)->next != NULL)
    {
        *first = (*first)->next;
    }
```

you assign new value to `*first`, thus effectively *forgetting* all elements except the last one.

Then you append a new element to the last one, so after each append action the list, as pointed at by the `l` variable, contains just last two elements.

A fix:

```
    list* last = *first;

    while(last->next != NULL)
    {
        last = last->next;
    }
    last->next = nouvElem;
```

You would avoid this mistake if you declared your function with appropriate `const` qualifier. As you do not want the `l` variable to be modified by the `insertFin` function, you should tell the compiler the variable pointed at by the `first` parameter is `const` (a non-modifiable pointer to a `list`):

```
void insertFin(list* const * first, int x)
{
    ....
}
```

Then compiler will reject the assignment:

```
    *first = ...;
```

and generate an error message.

Comment: yeah, it worked now ! seems i still not familiar with LL yet!

Comment: @MhennaouiMohamed Please see the expanded answer.

Comment: @CiaPan, I print out the address of l (in the main) and premier(in the function) and they show different address. Why is this happening? The pointer is passed as argument, therefore shouldn;t it be the same?

Comment: @Confidenc3 I am really not sure, _what_ pointer you print: `l` or `&l`...? `first`, &first` or `*first`...? _How_ are you printing them?

Comment: @CiaPan
1)I am printing in the main printf("%p\n", l);
2)In the function insertFin printf("%p\n", premier);
They are supposed to be pointing to the same spot, right?

Comment: @Confidenc3 Alas ...no. The `l` variable points at the first element in your list, the parameter `first` in your function points at `l`. If you want to check the pointers' consistency, do `printf("L:%p\n", l);` in `main()` and `printf("F:%p\n", *first);` in `insertFin()`.